# Why does ld's KEEP() does not keep my symbols?

Tags: gcc, ld, linker-scripts

Normally, by using KEEP(), ld keeps the symbols in the section even if symbols are not referenced. However, this is not my experience. I cannot create an ld linkerscript that retains symbols if they are not referenced.

Are there some preconditions for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KEEP *does* keep my symbols, but the presented archives were stripped beforehand of all the object files that were deemed to be unnecessary. To prevent that, the option `--whole-archive` must be used in the link command.

From the man page of `ld`:

> ```
>    --whole-archive
>        For each archive mentioned on the command line after the
>        --whole-archive option, include every object file in the archive in
>        the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object
>        files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared
>        library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting
>        shared library.  This option may be used more than once.
>
>        Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn't know
>        about this option, so you have to use -Wl,-whole-archive.  Second,
>        don't forget to use -Wl,-no-whole-archive after your list of
>        archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your
>        link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well.
> ```